# Spring Batch: Process huge amount of XML Files

Tags: xml, spring-batch

I'm newbie with Spring Batch and I can't achieve the requirement of my project. I need process a huge amount of files in a folder (with xml extension), change a minimal data inside each.

I'm reading and I have created a `MultiResourceItemReader<?>` and it read all files and pass the data to the processor.

My problem is that the `MultiResourceItemReader<?>` reads all files and I want to process file by file:

```
XML1IN.xml --> XML1OUT.xml
XML2IN.xml --> XML2OUT.xml
XML2IN.xml --> XML2OUT.xml
```

I can't found some like *ResourceReader* that passes me a file and my processor executes the operation.

Can someone help me?

Comment: `I can't found some like ResourceReader that passes me a file`: so an item in your case is a File, aka you are looking for an `ItemReader<File>` or `ItemReader<Resource>`, correct? Is your processor capable of doing the entire operation given a file or you need to read each file item by item? Can you give some numbers (how many files, average file size, etc)? I'm thinking of partitioning but before that, I want to make sure if it is really necessary depending on your numbers.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine! Thank you for your comment. I need to process 300k files by day. Each file is about 10Mb.

Comment: ok thanks. You did not specify what is an item in your case, are you looking for an `ItemReader<File>` or `ItemReader<Resource>`? Is your processor capable of doing the entire operation given a file or you need to read each file item by item? This is important to help you choose the best approach in designing your job.

Answer (score -1):

Consider doing the transformations using XSLT 3.0 with Saxon:

```
<xsl:for-each select="collection($folder)">
   <xsl:result-document href="....">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you use Saxon-EE this will run in multiple threads to make maximum use of multi-core and multi-CPU hardware performance.